# Information about fee via 3ds secure protocol

Tags: banking, online-banking, online-payment, russia

I've made a transaction between my 2 cards issued by different Financial institutions (Banks). I've confirmed the transaction amount in 3DS window. But the total amount was decreased on a fee volume. This fee was billed by a Bank whose card was used to transfer from.

Is it required by 3DS standard to inform a cardholder about the net transfer value = amount - fee? Didn't my Bank break some of regulations - it informed me only about the amount without fee?

Transfer from MasterCard to Visa. Both Debit Cards.

Answer (score 1):

I've consulted the Bank's stuff, they give the fillowing answer: 3DS service is used for verification only, it knows nothing about Banks fees.
Also the tranfer was made from InternetBank client of target card Bank. It also knows nothing about source Banks fees.

In this situation unfortunately there were not technical possibility to inform me about fees.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you were both the merchant and consumer in this transaction. This is generally against the terms of service for credit cards.

That aside, merchants always pay a percent of the transaction as a fee. It's how credit cards work.